# Filter no ng-repeat filtrar o parametro que passei no get

Tags: angularjs, filter

Olá, estou passando um parametro pela minha rota e preciso resgatar registros com esse parametro atraves de um ng-repeat.

```
$routeProvider.when("/detalhe/:placa", {
    templateUrl : 'view/detalhe.html',
    controller  : 'detalheCtrl'
});
```

Mas não estou conseguindo resgata-lo no meu filtro dentro do ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {placa: ???}">
   {{item.nome}}
</div>
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como posso pesquisar por isso? Pois tenho pesquisado e tenho encontrado apenas referências a filtros em cambo de busca de input.

Este é meu controller:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("detalheCtrl", function($scope, $http, estoqueAPI) {
$scope.loading = true;

var carregarEstoque = function () {
    estoqueAPI.getEstoque()
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.carros = data;
    }).finally(function() { $scope.loading = false; })
};

carregarEstoque(); 
});
```

Comment: Mostre seu controller "detalheCtrl", para que possamos lhe ajudar!

Comment: Pronto fernando, o meu controller é esse que postei.

Comment: Pergunta editada, obrigado pelas observações. Alguma idéia sobre solução do meu problema Fernando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu controller, você tem acesso aos parâmetros da rota por meio do [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams). Então é possível guardar isso como um model, e usar a referência dele no filtro:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("detalheCtrl", function($scope, $http, $routeParams, estoqueAPI) {
    $scope.loading = true;

    this.placaSelecionada = $routeParams.placa;

    var carregarEstoque = function () {
        estoqueAPI.getEstoque()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.carros = data;
        }).finally(function() { $scope.loading = false; })
    };

    carregarEstoque(); 
});
```

E o `ng-repeat` ficaria assim:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {placa: placaSelecionada}">
   {{item.nome}}
</div>
```

Existem outras soluções, como separar toda a parte de acesso a dados como um serviço, mas acredito que essa seja a mais simples dado o código que você já tem.

Comment: Valeu bfavaretto, fiz apenas uma pequena alteração em this.placaSelecionada = $routeParams.placa; para $scope.placaSelecionada = $routeParams.placa; para funcionar como esperado. Muito obrigado!